# no function clause matching in Access.get/3 - Why am I getting this error?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am getting this error when I try to get the list from the database, and I don't understand why.

This is the function that throws the error:

```
  def list_lectures do
    Lecture
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload(:author [user: :credential])
  end
```

And this is the error I get when I run the code:

```
iex(1)> Ram.CMS.list_lectures
[debug] QUERY OK source="lectures" db=3.4ms decode=0.7ms queue=0.4ms
SELECT l0."id", l0."source", l0."theme", l0."time", l0."title", l0."author_id", l0."inserted_at", l0."updated_at" FROM "lectures" AS l0 [] 
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3    

    The following arguments were given to Access.get/3:

        # 1
        :author

        # 2
        [user: :credential]

        # 3
        nil

    Attempted function clauses (showing 5 out of 5):

        def get(%module{} = container, key, default)
        def get(map, key, default) when is_map(map)
        def get(list, key, default) when is_list(list) and is_atom(key)
        def get(list, key, _default) when is_list(list)
        def get(nil, _key, default)

    (elixir) lib/access.ex:265: Access.get/3
    (ram) lib/ram/cms.ex:24: Ram.CMS.list_lectures/0
iex(1)>
```

```
  schema "lectures" do
    field :source, :string
    field :theme, :string
    field :time, :string
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :author, Author

    timestamps()
  end
```

```
  schema "credentials" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string
    belongs_to :user, User

    timestamps()
  end
```

```
schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :role, :string
    has_one :credential, Credential

    timestamps()
  end
```

This is the project link: https://github.com/DavidNeumark/ram

Comment: I think preloads should be `[:author,  [user: :credential]]`. You're missing semicolon.

Comment: Thanks, TheAnh, I tried to do what you said but I still have problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Access.get/3](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.9.2/lib/elixir/lib/access.ex#L259) document says:

> Gets the value for the given key in a container (a map, keyword list, or struct that implements the Access behaviour).

Your first argument give to Access.get/3:

:author is not map, keyword list or struct. It's atom.

I guess you want to preload nested association so it should be like this:

```
  def list_lectures do
    Lecture
    |> Repo.all()
    |> Repo.preload(author: [user: :credential])
  end
```

**Update** : After checking your github, [lib/ram/cms/lecture.ex](https://github.com/DavidNeumark/ram/blob/df72df5c8725697b6d881dc9333da67f65745473/lib/ram/cms/lecture.ex) missed an alias for Author. It causes above code doesn't work

```
defmodule Ram.CMS.Lecture do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias Ram.CMS.Author

  schema "lectures" do
    field :source, :string
    field :theme, :string
    field :time, :string
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :author, Author

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(lecture, attrs) do
    lecture
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :time, :source, :theme])
    |> validate_required([:title, :time, :source, :theme])
  end
end
```

Comment: I modified my answer, check it out

Comment: Yes, it was really missing the "alias" and I already updated the project on Github ... but I still have the error. I tried to run Ram.Repo.all () on iex and also threw an error. Maybe you have any ideas on how to find the solution?

Comment: What is that error? As I checked, above issue has been resolved after modify list_lectures function at **Repo.preload(author: [user: :credential])** and add missed Author alias on Lecture schema

Comment: @Minh-Khang can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65183075/add-interval-to-timestamp-using-ecto-fragments