# Add interval to timestamp using Ecto Fragments

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to write the following query in a phoenix application using Ecto fragments:

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
  inserted_at + interval '1 day' * expiry as deadline
  from friend_referral_code
) t
where localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC' > deadline
```

The value of expiry is an integer value that represents number of days. What I've got so far is something like this:

```
query = from frc in FriendReferralCode,
  where: fragment("localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC'") > fragment("? + INTERVAL '1' * ?", frc.inserted_at, frc.expiry)

FriendReferralCode
|> Repo.all(query)
|> Enum.each(fn frc -> update_friend_referral_code_users(get_friend_referral_code_users_by(receiver_id: frc.id), %{status: false}) end)
|> IO.puts()
```

end

but it throws the following error:

```
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Keyword.merge/2
            (elixir 1.11.2) lib/keyword.ex:764: Keyword.merge([], #Ecto.Query<from f0 in Stakester.Accounts.FriendReferralCode, where: fragment("localtimestamp at time zone 'UTC'") > fragment("? + INTERVAL '1 day' * ?", f0.inserted_at, f0.expiry)>)
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver how to write it in elixir using fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after [`Ecto.Query.API.ago/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#ago/2) and [`Ecto.Query.API.from_now/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#from_now/2) for querying interval *and* [`Ecto.Query.subquery/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2) for inner `select`.

---

Also, [`Repo.all/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:all/2) expects a query as a first argument, while you pass `FriendReferralCode` as the first argument in the call to `Repo.all/2`, where it expects a query, and `query` as a second one, where it expects a keyword list of options.

Do just `query |> Repo.all()` instead.

Comment: can you please look at my query and tell me where I am wrong? @AlekseiMatiuskhkin

Comment: As you could see from the error message, the query (this particular piece of) was built correctly. If you expect to receive any meaningful help, please, share the code, full error message, and point to the part where you’ve struggled.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the elixir code, please review

Comment: ah!! such a dumb mistake. Thank you very much